# How to eliminate code repetition?

Tags: c++, arduino, ide

How can I reduce code repetition in the following snippet:

```
  if(motionIOS == 0) 
  {
    if(character == 40)
    {
      previousMotion = character;
    }
      if(previousMotion == 40 && character == 50)
      {
        motionIOSValue = 50;
      }
    else
    {
    previousMotion = character;
    }
  }

  if(motionIOS == 1) 
  {
    if(character == 60)
    {
      previousMotion = character;
    }
      if(previousMotion == 60 && character == 70)
      {
        motionIOSValue = 70;
      }
    else
    {
    previousMotion = character;
    }
  }
```

In essence I am doing the same code twice, but with the values changes for some things. I will even need to use this code many more times too with variable numbers.

I think I should refactor it into a function, but do not know how.

Comment: Using `switch case` maybe: https://ideone.com/fjkNgT#cmperr

Comment: i did think of that, and thanks for it, but i want to reduce the length of the code. Something where i can just enter values for thigns such as motionIOD, charcter etc. if you see what  I mean?

Comment: Refactoring the code into a function/method is definitely applicable here. it would help to post a bigger snippet to show the context where this code is, and where the variables are defined (e.g. are they members of a class?)

Answer (score 0):

you can consolidate your condition checks.

```
if(motionIOS == 0 && previousMotion == 40 && character == 50) {
    motionIOSValue = 50;
} else if (motionIOS == 1 && previousMotion == 60 && character == 70){
    motionIOSValue = 70;
} else {
    previousMotion = character;
}
```

You can extract the condition check to another class if you want.

```
bool updateIosValue(int previousMotion, int character, int testMotion, int testCharacter){
    //do your custom checks here.
    return previousMotion==testMotion && character== testCharacter;
} 

if(motionIOS==0 && updateIosValue(previousMotion, character, 40, 50){
    motionIOSValue = 50;
}else if(motionIOS==1 && updateIosValue(previousMotion, character, 60, 70){
    motionIOSValue = 70;
}else{
    previousMotion = character;
}
```